# Bazaar split and & Rich Roots

Tags: bazaar

I would like to make a directory of my branch into a seperate repository.  `bzr split <dir>` looks like the coomand but I get

```
    bzr: ERROR: To use this feature you must upgrade your branch at file:///C:/blahblah/ to a format which supports rich roots.
```

What does that mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current trunk that you're using (at `C:\blahblah`) does not support rich roots (older versions of Bazaar use `pack-0.92` by default, which apparently is not rich-root compatible).

You need to use `bzr upgrade` to upgrade your branch, as the error message says.  A couple of the possible arguments to `bzr upgrade` include:

- `--rich-root`
- `--rich-root-pack`
- `--1.9-rich-root`

Try `bzr help upgrade` for more details, or see [Bazaar's page on upgrading branches](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/FormatUpgrades).

Comment: The recommended rich-root formats today are:
`--rich-root-pack` (supported in bzr 1.0 and up), `--1.9-rich-root` (supported in bzr 1.9 and up), `--1.14-rich-root` (supported in bzr 1.14 and up) and the latest one `2a` (supported in bzr 1.18 and up). It's recommended to use the latest format supported among all your installed bzr versions.